# schlage privacy set door knobs

Tags: lock

Gold coloured. Model unknown.  Took the handles off to paint/update them, now the knobs just will not operate the mechanism at all. Knobs will not turn or operate thestriking mechanism. No, it has nothing to do with the painting process.  It just needs some adjustment about which I know nothing. HELP!!

Comment: Is this a mortise set (mechanism fits into a pocket cut into the side of the door, knobs are typically on a square shaft that runs through the door), or cylindrical (rectangular mechanism fits into a hole drilled through the door, with only the latch extending from that hole out to the edge of the door), or rim (mounted on the surface of the door)? I'm guessing it's a modern cylindrical set, but knobs not turning is more typical of mortise reassembly error.

Comment: Pictures, please! They will vastly increase the odds that someone may be able to help you, particularly if you take them with the knobs not on the door so the mechanism can be seen.

Comment: Please provide more information and preferably images.  We can all appreciate, or at least I know I can, the frustration that can come with home improvement projects but without more information there is not much we can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

Making a wild assumption since we don't have enough information: I'm guessing that what you have is a grade-3 Schlage cylindrical privacy set of the sort that's available from every hardware store in the country. There are three pieces to this unit -- an outer knob with a hole in it, an inner knob with the thumbturn, and the latch mechanism.

The [installation guides on the Schlage website](http://www.schlage.com/content/dam/sch-us/documents/pdf/installation-manuals/p515-445-sh2-c.pdf) are for one-side-keyed knobs, but the principle is the same -- in fact, the mechanism is close to being the same.

If you look at step 6 in that guide (sorry, I don't have that one image by itself), you will notice that on the inner knob with the turnpiece, they tell you to look into the knob and make sure the slot is horizontal. If you look closely, you'll also see that the flat piece which runs from knob to knob is horizontal.

That's what you got wrong. It is possible to assemble the lock with these pieces rotated 90 degrees -- but only if you rotate them in opposite directions, with the result that they're both at their limit and each keeps the other from operating. This also has the side effect of tying up the knobs in the locked position.

(This is a general hazard when assembling mechanisms that are only designed to operate through part of their rotation rather than being able to spin endlessly. The position of the parts in this cycle is known as their "timing". You got the timing wrong.)

Remove the knobs, and reinstall them with the flat bar horizontal and the thumbpiece turned to match it. That should cure the problem, unless you've managed to do something more weird than usual.